# Flag panel no longer has "you have already raised this flag"

Tags: discussion, flags, user-interface

Previously, I was unable to select a flag when I had already flagged it, however now when I flag I am still able to select it, only to find when I have clicked it that "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention".  Is this a bug, and if so, can this be fixed?

Comment: That particular error message means you still have an *active* flag on that post (you can only have one active flag per post), not that you've already flagged with that reason. What type of flag did you cast on the post?

Comment: @animuson: I casted an NAA flag on a post, which was active when I found the same post by a different search and did not have that message.

Comment: This is by design. Irritating design, but not a bug.